# Responsive column layout with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve following layout with HTML/CSS, where the navigation elements  "A" and "C" are situated above the main content "B" on small screen and distributed corresponding to the left "A" and right "C" on larger screens.

My goal is to use constant HTML-elements and only change CSS-styles based on media-queries.

How to achieve this?

```
 Mobile                Desktop
 (small screen)        (large screen)
 +-------------------+ +-----------------------------------+
 |    A    |    C    | |    A    |       B       |    C    |
 +-------------------+ +---------+               +---------+
 |         B         |           |               |
 |                   |           |               |
 |                   |           |               |
 |                   |           |               |
 |                   |           |               |
 |                   |           |               |
 +-------------------+           +---------------+
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“I'm asking you (the community) for suggestions on how to achieve this”_ -  suggestion: Go read [ask] please, do proper research (column layout with CSS ain’t exactly a new thing ...), and then show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I really don't understand the amount of down votes on this question. It initially had a good explanation, with a clear scheme, of what needed help with, and only lacked a HTML sample, and questionable if it at all were needed, as it was quite clear already. I've seen similar where the question been upvoted

Comment: @Pharotek If you like, copy the now updated question into a new, notify me and I'll move my answer to that question and you can have this one deleted, as I think it doesn't earned all those down votes.

Comment: @LGSon Thank you a lot for your help! I have to wait 7 days now, before asking again...

Comment: Then simply delete this one and repost later if you find that the best. Here is a fiddle of my sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/dmy6ptw8/

Comment: I also deleted my answer, though can easily put it back.

Comment: Smart A* C-Level-Bro

Answer (score 1):

I think flexbox would help here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Set a display: flex on the container div and play a bit with the alignment as described in the linked article.

Answer (score -1):

Use media queries on css.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  //Display as u want the tables or divs for small devices
  //Change width as desired
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  //Display as u want the tables or divs for big devices or desktop
  //Change width as desired
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using HTML and CSS only, we can't achieve this requirement. If you use bootstrap in your code. You can able to achieve.

In bootstrap, we have **responsive utilities** concept is there using that you can build your above requirement

[For your reference](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: Of course this can be done using HTML/CSS ... and since bootstrap also uses that, well, then it shouldn't be able either?